# Updating xml content in webpage

Tags: c#-4.0

I load an XML document from a webpage. I can retrieve the value of an XML element from that document. Is there any way through which I can modify the value so that it also gets updated in the webpage also? This should be done using c#

I can change the value locally. I have to update it in the webpage XML also

Comment: Hello ! Could you share what you tried? We are happy to help but we won't write you code :)

Comment: XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load("URI");  //Ip address of the printer
            string text= document.GetElementsByTagName("fw:WSDiscovery")[0].InnerText;
            document.GetElementsByTagName("fw:WSDiscovery")[0].InnerText = "disabled";
            Console.WriteLine("set");
            document.Save("URI");
            string text1 = document.GetElementsByTagName("fw:WSDiscovery")[0].InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine(text1);
            Console.ReadLine();

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily like below:

```
var newValue = ...; //your new value here
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); //create xmldocument object

xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile); //load your file

XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Root/Node/Element");
node.Attributes[0].Value = newValue; //setting the value

xmlDoc.Save(xmlFile); //saving the updated document
```

**Updated Answer:**

Try using XPathNavigator class,

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("xml source");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("app", "xmlns"); //second argument is the xmlns on top of your xml file

foreach (XPathNavigator nav in navigator.Select("//app:node", manager))
{
    if (nav.Value == "0")
    {
        nav.SetValue("1");
    }
}
```

More info about said class can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/modify-xml-data-using-xpathnavigator)

Comment: Yeah I could do this way. But I am loading the xml content from a web page. Hence I am using a URI in the place of load(xmlfile) .But I could not use the same in save() method. It throws argument mismatch exception